# Devel Show Queries

Tags: mysql, performance, drupal, drupal-6

I may be missing something obvious here, but in the devel module settings I have checked "Collect query info" and "Display query log", and saved. Where does this information show up? I don't see anything different when I load pages. Is there a variable that I need to inject somewhere in my templates that I missed? I would like to view what queries are executing on each page and the amount of time they are taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should show up in `$closure` in your theme, unless you have something like [Admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) installed. In that case, it shows up in the Admin menu under the *Devel* section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it working, although it ended up being something messed up with my install. Good to know about $closure though!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mark Trapp's answer: you need a permission set: "display devel output". Users without that permisison will see no development output.

Answer (score 0):

Check user permissions - there is a specific permission allowing you to view the devel logs.  No permission=see nothing at all.